# regular expressions in exec sed

Tags: regex, seq

Could you help me with regular expressions in exec sed?

Example code:

```
<?php            echo "This code need to delete"; ?><? echo 'This code need to keep'; ?>
```

I need to delete:
    `<?php echo "This code need to delete"; ?>`

In all files, and keep
    `<? echo 'This code need to keep'; ?>`

I tried to do it like this:

```
find ./ -type f -name \*.php -exec sed -i -r 's/<\?php.*\?>//g' {} \;
```

But this way doesn't work correctly. (delete all code)

Comment: `<\?\s*php\s+echo\s+".*";\s*\?>`?

Answer (score 2):

Use a negated character class instead of `.*` because `.*` is greedy which matches any character as much as possible.

```
find ./ -type f -name \*.php -exec sed -i -r 's/<\?php[^>]*\?>//g' {} \;
```

You could use `-name '*.php'` instead of `-name \*.php` in the above.

**Example:**

```
$ echo '<?php            echo "This code need to delete"; ?><? echo 'This code need to keep'; ?>' | sed -r 's/<\?php[^>]*\?>//g'
<? echo This code need to keep; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using gnu awk you can do this to get rid of first `<?php...?>` block:

```
cat file
<?php          echo "This code need to delete"; ?><? echo 'This code need to keep'; ?>

awk -v RS='\\?>' '!/<\?php /{printf $0 RT}' file
<? echo 'This code need to keep'; ?>
```